# Bash : Find and Remove duplicate files from different folders

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two folders with some common files, I want to delete duplicate files   from `xyz` folder.

folder1:

```
/abc/file1.csv 
/abc/file2.csv
/abc/file3.csv
/abc/file4.csv
```

folder2:

```
/xyz/file1.csv
/xyz/file5.csv
```

I want to compare both folders and remove duplicate from `/xyz` folder. Output should be: `file5.csv`

For now I am using :

```
find "/xyz" "/abc" "/abc" -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -u | -exec rm {} \;
```

But it failing with reason : if `-exec` is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:

```
command-not-found -exec
-bash: -exec: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

`-exec` is an option to `find`, you've already exited the command `find` when you started the pipes.

Try [`xargs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) instead, it take all the data from stdin and appends to the program.

UNTESTED

```
find "/xyz" "/abc" "/abc" -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -u | xargs rm
```

Comment: Just on correction in my question   find "/xyz" "/abc" "/xyz" -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -u | xargs rm

Comment: Just one more question, what if I don't want to remove files, but move to other folder, how can we do that?

Comment: You can build whatever command you wish after `xargs`. You need to read up on the manual on how to use it in more complex commands. https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs

Answer (score 0):

Find every file in 234 and 123 directory get filename by -printf, sort them, uniq -d give list of duplications, give back path by sed, using 123 directory to delete the duplications from, and pass files to xargs rm

Command:

```
find ./234 ./123 -type f -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -d | sed 's/^/.\/123\//g' | xargs rm
```

sed don't needed if you are in the ./123 directory and using full path for folders in find.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: just find the files in abc and attempt to remove them from xyz:

UNTESTED

```
find /abc -type f -printf 'rm -f /xyz/%P' | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

## Remove Duplicate Files From Particular Directory

```
FileList=$(ls)
for D1 in $FileList ;do
if [[ -f $D1 ]]; then

for D2 in $FileList ;do
if [[ -f $D2 ]]; then


if [[ $D1 == $D2 ]]; then
: 'Skip Orignal File'
else

if [[ $(md5sum $D1 | cut -d'=' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 ) == $(md5sum $D2 | cut -d'=' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 ) ]]; then
echo "Duplicate File Found : $D2"
rm -rf $D2

fi #Detect Duplicate Using MD5
fi #Skip Orginal File


fi #D2 File available Then Next
done
fi #D1 File available Then Next
done
```